# DataTables Table jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery, jquerymobile

I was going through the site http://www.datatables.net/.There is an example which is shown in the site. 
[image]

When this particular example is seen in TAB or mobile the columns are sorted out like below - 
[image]

Can anyone help me out how this can be achieved in visualforce page. 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is based on [responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive) for jquery datatables. If you reduce the width of your browser window, you can observer this behaviour.

To create responsive datatable you need include code like:

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
    'responsive': true,
    ...
} );
```

Great example how to use jquery datatables within VF page inline with JS Remoting you can find [here](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/connecting-datatables-to-json-generated-by-apex)

```
j$('#table').dataTable({
    'responsive': true,
    'aoColumns': aoColumns,
    'bProcessing': true,
    'bServerSide': true,
    'bFilter': false,
    'sAjaxSource': 'fakeUrl',
    'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(aoData));
        // Call the @RemoteAction JavaScript function
        DataTableController.contacts(aoData, function(result, event) {
            if (event.type != 'exception') {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                for (var i = 0; i < result.aaData.length; i++) {
                    var r = result.aaData[i];
                    for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
                        var field = fields[j];
                        if (r[field] == undefined) {
                            // DataTables pops a dialog for undefined values
                            r[field] = null;
                        } else if (field == 'Birthdate') {
                            // Dates transmitted as longs
                            var d = new Date(r[field]);
                            r[field] = ''
                                    + (d.getMonth() + 1)
                                    + '/'
                                    + d.getDate()
                                    + '/'
                                    + d.getFullYear()
                                    ;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Call back into the DataTable function
                fnCallback(result);
            } else {
                alert(event.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The key point here is fnServerData, where you make call to server through JS Remoting.